# viewing a polygon read from shapefile with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, shapefile

I am trying to view a basic polygon read from a Shapefile using matplotlib and [pyshp](https://code.google.com/p/pyshp/)
But all my efforts yield just an empty axes with no polygon. Here are few of my tries, using the dataset showing the [borders of Belgium](http://www.gadm.org/country):

```
import shapefile as sf
r = sf.Reader("BEL_adm/BEL_adm0")
p=r.shapes()
b=p[0]
points = b.points

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
imporst matplotlib.patches as patches

verts = points

verts = []
for x,y in points:
    verts.append(tuple([x,y]))

codes = ['']*len(verts)
codes[0] = Path.MOVETO
codes[-1] = Path.CLOSEPOLY

for i in range(1,len(verts)):
    codes[i]=Path.LINETO

path = Path(verts, codes)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
patch = patches.PathPatch(path, facecolor='orange', lw=2)
ax.add_patch(patch)
ax.set_xlim(-2,2)
ax.set_ylim(-2,2)
plt.show()
```

Another try with patches also yields an empty frame:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11.7,8.3))

ax = plt.subplot(111)
x,y=zip(*b.points)
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
bol=patches.Polygon(b.points,True, transform=ax.transAxes)

ax.add_patch(bol)
ax.set_ylim(0,60)
ax.set_xlim(0,200)
plt.show()
```

Would be happy to see what I am missing.
Thanks, Oz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of calling `set_xlim(), set_ylim()` to set the range of axis, you can use `ax.autoscale()`.

For your Polygon version, you don't need to set transform argument to ax.transAxes, just call:

```
bol=patches.Polygon(b.points,True)
```

Comment: thanks, I really didn't understand how these methods works, it was really plotting the polygon, but it was outside my frame. ax.autoscale() worked with the combination of removing the transformation.