# plot shapefile in python

Tags: python, shapefile

I have a couple shape files that I want to plot some `scatterplot` data on top of that.

Does anyone have a way to load a shape file then plot it? 
I've followed a couple of tutorials, but have not been successful so far.

The shape file, I am trying to use is one of the roads in Pakistan.
Found  [Here](http://www.mapcruzin.com/free-pakistan-arcgis-maps-shapefiles.htm)

I downloaded the modules `pyshp` and `shapelib` but am open to others!

Comment: Similar question, plotting with matplotlib http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871085/viewing-a-polygon-read-from-shapefile-with-matplotlib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Helpful tutorial for shapefiles and using basemap to plot maps: http://www.packtpub.com/article/plotting-geographical-data-using-basemap

Answer (score 1):

As much as i love D3, Matplotlib and R, this sounds like you just want create an overlay above a Google Maps chart.

This is easier than you might expect:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays

Comment: yes, that seems like it might work. I'd like to output a jpg/pdf of the file. Do you know if it's possible?

Comment: @user1253952 Not sure if google maps natively support pdf snapshots, but this tool will do it for you! http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Qgis](http://qgis.org/en/) for that purpose.

It has a python console that enables you to treat data in an efficient way.
It also reads and writes .shp-files.